# Windows seems to lose track of .NET application

Tags: c#, .net, windows, windows-installer

We have a .NET application that we distribute to our users via an MSI installer package.  We have C++ applications that run each morning to see if the user's copy of the application is out of date, and if so, we pull down the new MSI and install it.  If the application is running, we need to take it down so we can perform the update.

Our problem is that every once in a while it seems like windows "loses" our application.  It will not report that the process is running - though it is.  It will allow us to overwrite, or even delete, the in-use executable file without taking down the application.

Maybe this is something that is common -- but we can't figure out what is going on!  Does anyone have any insight into this situation?

It seems like a temporary copy of our application is getting created, and the program is getting ran from that.  But if that is the case, why doesn't it happen all the time?

EDIT:
In our program, We are using the "EnumProcesses" function from the Platform SDK, PSAPI.dll, to enumerate all of the running processes.

Comment: What do you use to detect if the application is running?

Comment: Says it is not running *and* allows overwriting the executables?  There's a simple explanation for that: it isn't running.

Comment: Don't know what your app does, but it sure sounds like ClickOnce would be a cleaner solution.

Comment: Are all the thread being released properly at shut down of the application?

Comment: I wish "it wasn't running" was the solution ;)  However, I am continuing to use the application.  Task Manager says it is running, but the script does not.  Whats weirder to me than just not detecting it is the fact that I can override the executable while continuing to use the app.  Let me see if I can dig up the script.

Comment: How do you verify that the program is or isn't running, outside of your installation program? What I mean is this: You say that the program is running, yet you can delete and overwrite the executable file. How do you know or verify that the program is running? Is the program window on-screen? Do you see it in task manager process tab?

Comment: It is a GUI application, so it sits on the screen.  Task Manager shows that the process is running.  However, it still allows me to overwrite and delete the exe file.  I performed a search to make sure there was not another exe file on the system named the same, and there is not.

Also, despite Task Manager stating that it is running, the EnumProcesses function is not coming back with the process.

Answer (score 2):

Could it be that either the script or the application runs as a 64-bit program, and the other as a 32-bit program? If so, then on 64-bit machines the update check could be looking in the wrong location for an existing application and thus reporting it as missing?

Comment: Looking into this, it seems promising..  The application is 32-bit, not sure about the update script yet.  But, would this also somehow account for being able to override the executable?

Comment: This turns out not to be the case, but thank you for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

What mechanism are you using to check to see if the process is running or not?

Try using something like process explorer to see what path the executable image is loaded from - it should be listed in the modules section.

Comment: See the edit in my original question for the process enumeration mechanism.  I did not think of using process explorer, but that is a good idea.  Unfortunately we cannot recreate this on-demand, but I will keep that in mind when it happens again.